# creating a code that use .isdigit

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I was creating a code that use .isdigit. It goes like this:

```
a = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))

if 'a'.isdigit():

    b = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))

else:

    print "Your input is invalid."
```

But when I enter an alphabet, it doesn't come out the "Your input is invalid.
And if I entered a digit, it doesn't show the b, 'Enter 2nd number'.

Is there anyway anyone out there can help me see what's the issue with my code.
That will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: dont use int() just have a = input("...")

Comment: You're converting `a` to a number before checking if it's a digit, which doesn't seem logical. You should probably convert it after checking shouldn't you?

Comment: Well you immediately cast the input to an `int`, also you're testing the char `'a'` rather than the variable `a`

Comment: `'a'.isdigit()` will always be `False` because the letter `'a'` is not a digit. `a.isdigit()`, however, would depend on the value of `a`.

Comment: Please do not edit things like "[solved]" in your question title. Instead, accept the answer that helped you most, or if there are no answers (or none of them were the solution), post your own answer and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the input to a variable `a`, but when you try to query it with isdigit() you're actually querying a string `'a'`, not the variable you created.

Also, you are forcing a conversion to an int before you've even checked if it's an int. If you need to convert it to an int, you should do that after you run the .isdigit() check:

```
    a = raw_input("Enter 1st number: ")

if a.isdigit():

    a = int(a)
    b = int(raw_input("Enter 2nd number: "))

else:

    print("Your input is invalid.")
```

Comment: You could omit the `eval` call. It's not required.

Comment: _"To convert the input to a string (which you'll need to do to use .isdigit()), you want to use str(a)."_ - No you don't. No need to cast `a` to a string. `input` already returns a string by default.

Comment: Why have you used `eval` here at all?

Comment: Oh, that was because I was writing in Python 3 and automatically converted it. Forgot to remove it - I'll fix that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually, on second thought, the OP seems to be using Python 2, so `raw_input` should be used rather than bare `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your `a` variable to string type, like this:

```
a = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))

if str(a).isdigit():
    b = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))
else:

    print("Your input is invalid.")
```